# How do I upgrade my Ruby version in Windows using Instant Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7

If I'm using Instant Rails, how do I upgrade my Ruby version from 1.8.6 to 1.9.* which they say runs faster in Windows? What's the necessary Instant Rails console command? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative to consider.

You could just install ruby 1.9.2 (1.9.1 segfaults with Rails3 and isn't recommended ... make sure to install it to a different folder like c:\ruby192 or something) then use pik http://github.com/vertiginous/pik to switch the ruby version you're running.

I bet that would work just fine. Keep in mind that you'd have to install all your gems again though.

Comment: Okay, let me check it out. Thanks sir.